# Paired Comparison Testing for Best Color

Tags: hypothesis-testing, paired-comparisons, bradley-terry-model

Suppose I have a set of 5 colors and 3 judges whose job is to choose their favorite color in the set. Each judge will be shown a screen with 2/5 colors and then another new pair of colors from the set and then a new pair until all pairs are exhausted. For each pair, the judge would click and choose one out of the two colors that they like more before moving on to the next pair.

In this case, each judge should see 10 unique pairs of colors (n*(n-1)/2, where n is the number of colors) generated from the set of 5 colors. For a small number of colors this wouldn't take too much time but with, say, 50 colors there would be 1,225 pairs for a judge to click through!!

In the case of having 50 colors, is there a way that I could increase the number of judges to, say, 100 and then only show each judge 20 pairs of colors and then be able to infer the "global" or overall color winner?

What is the statistical test or analysis method that I am describing?

Comment: Why not just give people a list & ask them to rank the colors. Also, are you assuming that everyone will have the same preferential ordering? If not, what sense does this make? What is the larger goal for this project?

Comment: First, the list is actually of something else instead of color and, second, the list is probably closer to 200 items and the judges will only have patience to look at 10-20 pairs. The goal is to find the most popular by voting but not require the judges to have to tediously compare all colors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not a full answer but some potentially useful comments:

This kind of experimental design is also known as *paired comparisons* and a popular and simple stochastic model for it is the *Bradley-Terry model*. This tries to recover a latent *strength* for each object in the comparison by fitting a logistic regression model. It is also applicable if the subjects that do the rating do not see all $n \choose 2$ possible pairs. However, I'm not sure whether there are results how you have to design the experiment in order to get the full vector of all $n$ *strenghts* if you limit the number of comparisons for each subject. As the model is a simple logistic regression there may be results for GLMs that could be leveraged, though.

R packages implementing the Bradley-Terry and related models include: *prefmod* (http://dx.doi.org/10.18637/jss.v048.i10), *BradleyTerry2* (http://dx.doi.org/10.18637/jss.v048.i09), *eba*, *psychotools*, among others.

As for the application to color preferences: I would also doubt that you will get a winner (= color with the highest strength) whose strength *significantly* differs from the second- or third-ranked color in a design with 50 colors and only 100 judges. Also, one would have to keep in mind that the judges' preferences may vary or depend on further covariates etc.

Comment: Could this type of model be applied to, say, sports where not all teams have played each other but you could try to estimate the global ranking by looking at all of the teams who have played each other and inferring the rank between teams who have not played each other? Essentially, in the simplest case, if A beats B and B beats C, then we infer that A is ranked higher than C without requiring that A and C actually play against each other.

Comment: In principle this is possible but the model is stochastic, i.e, A beats B only with a certain probability. The advantage of this is that you get a natural explanation for intransitivities because even the weakest team beats the strongest with a certain probability. The outcome is also not just a _ranking_ but a _scaling_ that allows to compute distances between the strengths.